# Prove that $S^2$ is symplectic manifold

Tags: symplectic-geometry

How to show that $S^2$ is a symplectic manifold? What is the symplectic structure on $S^2$?

Comment: It would help if you included a little context for the question, so that potential answerers can better tailor an answer to your current understanding/context, but NB that on a surface any volume form is a symplectic form, so every oriented surface admits a symplectic structure.

Comment: i wanted to show specifically that $S^2$ is symplectic by seeing what is its symplectic structure